# Unable to place call from Mac using iPhone

Tags: iphone, mac, call

I have a Mac and and an iPhone. I want to make phone calls to my saved contacts from the Contacts app on my Mac without picking up my iPhone.

But when I click on the call icon in the Contacts app, Skype launches instead.

Calling via iPhone was working fine previously, but now Skype launches instead. I do not wish to use Skype.

I do not remember changing any settings, and I want the old behavior back to call from my iPhone and not from Skype installed on my Mac.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you installed Skype and it got configured as the default app for making telephone calls (default app your Mac would use to handle `tel:` links).

You can try to revert to the previous/default behavior by launching FaceTime app on your Mac, going to Preferences and opening the Settings tab. Look for the value selected for **Default for calls:** at the bottom and make sure FaceTime is selected.

[image: macOS Catalina FaceTime Preferences window]